# Correct order of adjectives

Tags: grammar, word-order, adjective-order

Is there any rule governing the order of adjectives, when we use consecutive adjectives? For example, is the order of the adjectives in the following sentence correct? I mean the order of "***his, some, other***"

> *Then, it was copied on parchment, with his some other texts*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a correct (or usual or idiomatic) ordering for adjectives, although it can sometimes be departed from to change the emphasis.  There are various accounts of it (which differ slightly in the details).

[Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/adjectives-order) lists the ordering as follows:

> **1** opinion *unusual, lovely, beautiful*,
> **2** size *big, small, tall*,
> **3** physical quality *thin, rough, untidy*,
> **4** shape *round, square, rectangular*,
> **5** age *young, old, youthful*,
> **6** colour *blue, red, pink*,
> **7** origin *Dutch, Japanese, Turkish*,
> **8** material *metal, wood, plastic*,
> **9** type *general-purpose, four-sided, U-shaped*,
> **10** purpose *cleaning, hammering, cooking*

The [British Council](https://learnenglish.britishcouncil.org/english-grammar-reference/adjective-order) summarises the main rules as follows:

> We usually put a general opinion in front of a specific opinion:
>
> *nice tasty soup*,
> *a nasty uncomfortable armchair*,
> *a lovely intelligent animal*

> We usually put an opinion adjective in front of a descriptive adjective:
>
> *a nice red dress*,
> *a silly old man*,
> *those horrible yellow curtains*

**Determiners**.  Determiners always come at the start.  So *the*, *that*, *his*, *some* always come at the start.

You cannot have two determiners at the start.  *His some other texts* is incorrect English.  We would just say *his other texts* or *some other texts* (or we could say *some of his other texts*).